# Firebase realtime database rules for a chat app

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, chat, firebase-security

Trying to put my question in its general concept so that your reply will stay relevant to all the ones who are stuck firebase rules for a chat app.

My chat database is a simple one and has 3 nodes: Messages / Connections / Users as below:

Database

```
-Messages
--message : 
--$uid
...

-Connections
--Connection1
--Connection2
--ConnectionX
...

-Users
--UID1
--UID2
```

Here's what I need to proofread pls for my realtime database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {

      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null" && "$uid/current_page" == "3w_stringofmywebsite/*",
        ".write": "auth != null" && "$uid/current_page" == "3w_stringofmywebsite/*"
      }

      // .read & .write to authenticated users & variable $uid/current_page= "3w_stringofmywebsite/*"  (allow access from requests from all pages from my web site only)
    }

    "connections": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null" && root.child(‘users’).child($uid).child(“current_page ") == "
            3 w_stringofmywebsite/*"
      }
                
      // .read to authenticated users & variable from another path “users/$uid/current_page” = "3w_stringofmywebsite/*"  (allow access from from all pages from my web site only)
    
    }
    
    "messages": {
      ".read" : "auth != null" && root.child(‘users’).child($uid).child(“current_page") == "3w_stringofmywebsite/*" ,
      ".validate": "auth!=null" && data.child('msg').val ().length <= 140 && data.child('msg').isString"
    }
    
    // .read to authenticated users & variable from another path “users/$uid/current_page” = "3w_stringofmywebsite/*"  (allow access from all pages from my web site only)
    // .write to authenticated users & variable “msg” is a string & < 140 characters
    
  }
```

Thank you for your generous correction to the code above so that it serves all other newcomers.

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own. They only become meaningful once they're exercised by your application code. Please edit your question to show the code that isn't doing what you expect it to do, and a clear description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dear Frank,

the syntax of commands has many errors (tried many times to do the corrections but the list is long) and I don't want to fill the ticket here with beginners mistakes.

=> what I need is someone who masters the syntax and relieve me from bumping my head at each step in each command!

*For the "users" node:
Read: right to only authenticated connections and the ones that are coming from my website only (as the chat tool is on this website)
Write: right similar to above.

*For the "connections" node:
Read to authenticated users &  the connections that are coming from my website [there's a variable "current_page" from another path “users/ "ABC"/current_page” = "3w_stringofmywebsite/*" that I can use to match the string of my website as a test

NB: "ABC" above is a string auto generated by the node and I don't know how I can point to the variable "current_page" below it since it keeps varying from one node entry to another!

*For the "messages" node:
Read: privilege to authenticated and again check if the variable “users/ "ABC"/current_page” is from my web site
Write: privilege to authenticated and the message is a string < 140 characters.

Appreciate your support in this.
Thank you.